# Using the $.extend plugin for jQuery on an undeclared variable

Tags: jquery, extend

[This page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) says to use:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

But I prefer to scope everything.  So if I had a local scope explicitly declared, could I use:

```
var local = {};
$.extend(local.object, object1, object2);
```

instead of saying this:

```
var local = {};
local.object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ever tried this approach?

```
var local = { object: {} }; 
$.extend(local.object, object1, object2);
```

btw, I didn't see problem with the third approach.

Comment: Nay, I don't like that syntax. I think I'll the the third approach.

Comment: Yeah, the third approach is better because it's got my beloved equal sign being used as an assignment, like I'm used to doing.